# Fbx exports without texture

Tags: texturing, .fbx

I want to export fbx with textures, I'm enabling path mode `copy` and switching on that button on the right, but always model exports without textures. I'm unsure what else needs to be done, tutorials don't mention anything else.

Comment: there's some information missing here, which blender version you are using and for what you are exporting your FBX into? (substance, maya, unreal, blender)

Comment: @Wolfeius newest blender (3.1.0 iirc), trying to export makehuman model to fbx to import it in unity3d again. I know that makehuman is ancient technology but I'm not doing this of my own free will.

Comment: this? https://gamedevtraum.com/en/blender-tutorials-and-curiosities/how-to-export-a-3d-model-in-fbx-format-with-textures-in-blender/

Comment: @Wolfeius yeah such thing doesn't work. I mean it works, but there are no textures.